# Tabbed activity and google fit api

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I created an app with 3 tabs(fragments) and in the first fragment i tried to use the api but nothing works as it suppose to, if i write the code for the api in the mainactivity it works fine. What am i doing wrong here? i am getting no errors in android studio!

here is the code form the fragment

```
public class Tab1Stepcounter extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1stepcounter, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

protected class Stepcounter extends AppCompatActivity implements

        OnDataPointListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

{
    private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
    private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
    private boolean authInProgress = false;
    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int progressStatus=0;
    private Handler handler= new Handler();
    private TextView textView;
    private Button toastButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab1stepcounter);

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
        }

        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        toastButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_toast);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        DataSourcesRequest dataSourceRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                .setDataTypes( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE )
                .setDataSourceTypes( DataSource.TYPE_RAW )
                .build();

        ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult> dataSourcesResultCallback = new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                for( DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources() ) {
                    if( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE.equals( dataSource.getDataType() ) ) {
                        registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mApiClient, dataSourceRequest)
                .setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultCallback);
    }

    private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType) {

        SensorRequest request = new SensorRequest.Builder()
                .setDataSource( dataSource )
                .setDataType( dataType )
                .setSamplingRate( 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
                .build();

        Fitness.SensorsApi.add( mApiClient, request, this )
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.e( "GoogleFit", "SensorApi successfully added" );
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if(!authInProgress){
            try{
                authInProgress = true;
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult( Stepcounter.this,REQUEST_OAUTH);
            }  catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e){}

        }else {
            Log.e( "GoogleFit" , "authInProgress" );
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if( requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH ) {
            authInProgress = false;
            if( resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
                if( !mApiClient.isConnecting() && !mApiClient.isConnected() ) {
                    mApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else if( resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED ) {
                Log.e( "GoogleFit", "RESULT_CANCELED" );
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("GoogleFit", "requestCode NOT request_oauth");
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
        for( final Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields() ) {
            final Value value = dataPoint.getValue( field );
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), field.getName() + " : " + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    textView.setText(field.getName()+ ": " + value);
                    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    progressStatus = value.asInt();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            toastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), field.getName() + " : " + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        Fitness.SensorsApi.remove( mApiClient, this )
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            mApiClient.disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(AUTH_PENDING, authInProgress);
    }

}

}
```

And here is the code form main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       switch (position) {
           case 0:
               Tab1Stepcounter tab1 = new  Tab1Stepcounter();
               return tab1;
           case 1:
               Tab2History tab2 = new  Tab2History();
               return tab2;
           case 2:
               Tab3Sesions tab3 = new  Tab3Sesions();
               return tab3;
           default:
               return null;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Step Counter";
            case 1:
                return "History";
            case 2:
                return "Sesions";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Just one note: a non static Activity inside of a Fragment seems wrong (`protected class Stepcounter extends AppCompatActivity` in your case).

Comment: well i install the app on my phone to see if it's working and it dosen't connect to the api, it should ask for my google account and then show in the text the steps i made

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Stepcounter` Activity is not started and hence the API is not invoked. You have a few options to solve this:

- Refactor the code so either your Tab1Stepcounter will be responsible for the initiation of the API.
- Move the API logic to the MainActivity.
- Start Stepcounter activity from within the Tab1Stepcounter fragment (your `onCreateView()` just inflates the view, it does not start the activity).

Comment: i am new to this tehnology, can u tell me how to use the first option?

Comment: i tried to use the startActivity(intent) method inside the onCreateView but now the app crashes

Comment: '    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1stepcounter, container, false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Stepcounter.class);
        Tab1Stepcounter.this.startActivity(intent);
        return rootView;
        }       '

Comment: It is an odd behavior for a tab to start an activity onCreateView() - maybe you can add a button on the fragment and when the user clicks it start the other activity.